# Installation strategies for Windows 10 on a 32Gb netbook

Tags: ssd, windows-10-upgrade, asus-laptop

I have just purchased an Asus T100TAF and I am considering whether to install Windows 10 on it.
Currently it comes with Windows 8.1 and it is purported to have 32GB SSD.

When I look at the Windows Manager on this device it appears to have a C: partion of only 20.8GB in size. Presumably some of this remaining 11GB is taken up with a recovery partition.

[image: T100TAF storage]

If I am to install Windows 10 on this machine, how much space will actually be left on the C: drive? Is it possible to recover space from the remainder of the other partition(s) that are not being displayed?

Are any specific strategies required to complete a Windows 10 upgrade with such little *elbow room* on the harddrive, such as attaching a portable drive, expanding partitions or configuring any specific settings during the upgrade?

Comment: "Presumably some of this remaining 11Gb is taken up with a recovery partition"  looking in the Disk Management console of Windows would confirm that for you/us, it's also where you'd go to mange your disks/partitions (ie: delete, extend, etc.). IMO, as-is, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 can use a feature called Compact OS to store system files as compressed files to reduce its disk use. A similar concept was WIMBoot in 8.1 but Compact OS offers ability to update individual files so its better. You can prepare a Compact OS deployment (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn940129(v=vs.85).aspx) or let Windows 10 do it for you after installation (http://www.nextofwindows.com/what-is-compact-os-in-windows-10-and-how-to-enable-it-to-save-disk-space). Using Compact OS on SSD disks should have the minimal effect on performance. (Many tablet brands use this method on their Windows 10 powered tablets.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up returning this machine to the shop because of an unrelated issue so I am unable to corroborate either of conflicting answers. If a third party were to post support a a detailed answer or an informed comment corroborating one of these answers I will gladly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will more than likely not have enough room, as the windows 10 upgrade process will need to keep the current OS intact for roll back if needed. If you go to microsofts site and download windows 10 you can use the windows 10 media creation tool, which will tell you if you have enough space and if not will allow you to store the current OS on an external hard drive during the upgrade (must be alteast 8gb)

Microsofts realizes lots of devices will be running this OS and have smaller, HD space, so they've put all the tools in place to make this happen. Good luck! I almost bought a T100 on cyber monday but backed out, kinda regret it :(

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up returning this machine to the shop because of an unrelated issue so I am unable to corroborate either of conflicting answers. If a third party were to post support a a detailed answer or an informed comment corroborating one of these answers I will gladly accept the answer.